# How can I add sub navigation to menu?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have config file where I have configured the `menuItems` array as follows. Which is `menu.json`

```
{
    "menuItems": [
        { "name": "Services", "link": "/services" },
        { "name": "References", "link": "/references" },
        { "name": "Careers", "link": "/careers" },
        { "name": "Our Story", "link": "/story" },
        { "name": "Contact Us", "link": "/contact" },
        { "name": "Guides", "link": "/guides"},
        { "name": "Blog", "link": "/blog" }
    ]
}
```

I have tried adding subMenuItems inside the menuItems array but so far it results in error in the query in the `useMenu.js`

```
{
        "menuItems": [
            { "name": "Services", "link": "/services", "subMenuItems": [ {"name": "Page", "link": "/page"}] },
            { "name": "References", "link": "/references" },
            { "name": "Careers", "link": "/careers" },
            { "name": "Our Story", "link": "/story" },
            { "name": "Contact Us", "link": "/contact" },
            { "name": "Guides", "link": "/guides"},
            { "name": "Blog", "link": "/blog" }
        ]
    }
```

Then in the querying the items inside the array here in the `useMenu.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { useLocale } from '../hooks/locale'

function useMenu() {
    // Grab the locale (passed through context) from the Locale Provider
    // through useLocale() hook
    const { locale } = useLocale()
    // Query the JSON files in <rootDir>/i18n/translations
    const { rawData } = useStaticQuery(query)

    // Simplify the response from GraphQL
    const simplified = rawData.edges.map(item => {
        return {
            name: item.node.name,
            menuItems: item.node.translations.menuItems,
        }
    })

    // Only return menu for the current locale
    const { menuItems } = simplified.filter(lang => lang.name === locale)[0]

    return menuItems
}

export default useMenu

const query = graphql`
    query useMenu {
        rawData: allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "menu" } }) {
            edges {
                node {
                    name
                    translations: childMenuJson {
                        menuItems {
                            link
                            name
                            subMenuItems {
                              link
                              name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

And then adding the subMenuItems to the query. Is this wrong way to do it? How would I be able to add the sub menu there? The menu itself is set here in the `navigation.js` file and is following:

```
import React from 'react'
import useMenu from '../useMenu'

import * as S from './styled'

const Navigation = ({ isActive, handleToggleMenu }) => {
    const [menuItems, subMenuItems] = useMenu()

    return (
        <>
            <S.Navigation>
                {menuItems.map((menu, index) => (
                    <S.NavigationLink
                        to={menu.link}
                        aria-label={menu.name}
                        activeClassName="active"
                        key={`${menu.link}${index}`}
                    >
                        {menu.name}
                    </S.NavigationLink>
                ))}
                {subMenuItems.map((subMenu, index) => (
                    <S.NavigationLink
                        to={menu.link}
                        aria-label={subMenu.name}
                        activeClassName="active"
                        key={`${subMenu.link}${index}`}
                    >
                        {subMenu.name}
                    </S.NavigationLink>
                ))}
            </S.Navigation>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

The error I am getting is following: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: What error appears? Please add some details about where are you setting the menu, the config files, etc

Comment: Any ideas how to solve it? @FerranBuireu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const [menuItems, subMenuItems] = useMenu()` here, you are importing your custom hook from `../useMenu`. This hook, since it's a custom-coded one, only accepts the exported values from your `useMenu.js` file so, it doesn't allow that notation because you are only exporting `menuItems`:

```
function useMenu() {
    // Grab the locale (passed through context) from the Locale Provider
    // through useLocale() hook
    const { locale } = useLocale()
    // Query the JSON files in <rootDir>/i18n/translations
    const { rawData } = useStaticQuery(query)

    // Simplify the response from GraphQL
    const simplified = rawData.edges.map(item => {
        return {
            name: item.node.name,
            menuItems: item.node.translations.menuItems,
        }
    })

    // Only return menu for the current locale
    const { menuItems } = simplified.filter(lang => lang.name === locale)[0]

    return menuItems // here, the only export
}
```

In addition, the way you use the state is not correct. When you set a state using `useState` hook, like:

```
const [value, setValue]= useState("hi");
```

Your state is held by `value`, so if you want to get the current state's value, you need to access to `value`, initially set to `"hi"`. `setValue` is just a helper function that is used to set the new state, so if you want to set a new value, overriding "hi", you need to use the setter function `setValue("new value")`.

Said that I can't know if your `useMenu.js` logic is correct, assuming that, I guess that you don't want two separate loops to get the `subMenuItems` data. You should do something like:

```
import * as S from './styled'

const Navigation = ({ isActive, handleToggleMenu }) => {
    const menuItems = useMenu()

    return (
        <>
            <S.Navigation>
                {menuItems.map((menu, index) => {
                    if(menu.subMenuItems){
                       menu.subMenuItems.map(submenuItem=>{
                          return console.log(submenuItem);
                       })
                    }
                    return <S.NavigationLink
                        to={menu.link}
                        aria-label={menu.name}
                        activeClassName="active"
                        key={`${menu.link}${index}`}
                    >
                        {menu.name}
                    </S.NavigationLink>
                })}

            </S.Navigation>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

Step by step, your state has changed to:

```
    const menuItems = useMenu()
```

Since you are exporting `menuItems`, your data is perfectly valid there. You have your `subMenuItems` inside the `menuItems`.

In the same loop where you are iterating through `menuItems`, you have the nested property of `subMenuItems` so, if your `menu` (the iterable variable) has the `subMenuItems` property, you want to iterate again trough it to get them. In this case, I'm returning a `console.log()` but adapt it to your navigation menu:

```
   if(menu.subMenuItems.length){
       menu.subMenuItems.map(submenuItem=>{
          return console.log(submenuItem);
       })
    }
```

Comment: I got following error when trying that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: What's inside `menu`? Can you debug it?

Comment: ```0:
link: "/services"
name: "Services"
subMenuItems: Array(1)
0: {link: "/blog", name: "Page"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
1: {link: "/references", name: "References", subMenuItems: null}
2: {link: "/careers", name: "Careers", subMenuItems: null}
3: {link: "/story", name: "Our Story", subMenuItems: null}
4: {link: "/contact", name: "Contact Us", subMenuItems: null}
5: {link: "/guides", name: "Guides", subMenuItems: null}
6: {link: "/blog", name: "Blog", subMenuItems: null}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Getting following now `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: Can you create a working sandbox? It must be a silly issue but without debugging more it's difficult to guess. Try to loop step by step. In the main loop add the proper condition to loop to `subMenuItems`

Comment: I wasn't able to create it and make it work on codesandbox. Is there other way?

Comment: Debugging your loop and place the correct code.

Comment: Should i do it as a separate entity and then show if if the name is this with condition and css?

Comment: The native way is to use one loop and make another nested loop if your item has `subMenuItems` property. Of course, everything should be styled.

Comment: i got this show in console also from the submenuitem console log  `{link: "/blog", name: "Page"}
link: "/blog"
name: "Page"`

Comment: From there, you can create the menu elements. You are only missing the case when an element has `subMenuItems`

Comment: Like that? Updated my question with the navigation file?

Comment: It look better now. What's the issue?

Comment: About the styling. I am using styled component and wondering how re structure it to add the sub nav menu styling there. Updated the file in the questions

Comment: This issue has been solved. Now the details regarding styles depend strongly on your needs, your design, etc. It's just a matter of trial/error.